# How can I use chrome://flags/ #enable-force-dark and still see dropdown menus' content?

Tags: google-chrome, dark-mode

How can I use chrome://flags/ `#enable-force-dark` and still see dropdown menus' content?

For example, on https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html,  with `#enable-force-dark` activated:

[image]

The [Dark Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en-US) Google Chrome extension works but I don't want to use it because it is making page loading too slow:

[image]